# django-pyodbc: my odbc driver on my old machine worked but now I'm getting a error saying my driver "doesn't support modern datatime types"

Tags: python, sql-server, django, odbc

I'm trying to develop an app in Django. I recently got a new work machine and that is the only thing that has changed.

My last computer was running Windows 7. The server is running Windows 7 enterprise. My new computer is running Windows 10 pro. My database is being run in SQL Server 2012.

I'm using the `django-pyodbc-azure` package.

Error:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The database driver doesn't support modern datatime types.`

here's my database setup:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'auth',
        'HOST': 'x.x.x.x',
        'PORT': '',
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
         },
    },
    'EZCORP': {
        'NAME': 'database',
        'HOST': 'x.x.x.',
        'PORT': '',
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
            'dsn': 'mydsn',
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the ODBC connections set up on the computer. I needed to download the proper driver (SQL Server Native Client 11.0) and create the ODBC connection *using that odbc driver*. Then everything works fine!